# Background fetch calling once ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, background-process, multitasking

This is my first question in SO , sorry if i am not following any guidelines .

I am implementing ios7 background fetch in my older app.But only problem is that i have to do simulate the location in xcode .
I have implemented the code like in http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html .

My questions are - 
1) will this be called regularly (lets say 30 second) on device ?
2) Do i need to simulate background fetch always for testing on device  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the simulate background fetch feature to verify the logic which is executed upon a background fetch. i.e. whatever code does the fetching.

You must set the minimum fetch interval. Typically, you’ll set this to `UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum` to fetch as **often** as allowed:

You can set it like this:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];

    return YES;
}
```

The default value is UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalNever, so if you fail to set the value on launching, your app will never be woken up to perform background fetches. The value you provide is the minimum number of seconds between wakes; do note, however, that the value is merely advisory—your application may perform fetches less or more often.

Setting UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum will ensure your application is called as regularly as possible, but in reality the system will decide ultimately.

---

[source](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/09/ios-7-background-fetch/)

Comment: john:I have implemented and done whatever you told me in  the code and install the app on ios7 device but looks like it is not calling the webservices :( . any suggestion will be appreciable .

Comment: Follow this tutorial, (read all of it) http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-working-with-background-fetch--mobile-20520

Comment: the key was - ios will call background fetch method regularly but not in particular time interval :) thanks john

Comment: @MarcusAdams what? I didn't plagiarise anything. I linked to the same tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

you can use NSTimer in performFetchWithCompletionHandler:

```
    var time = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(callTime , target: self, selector: #selector(self.notific), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    completionHandler(.NewData)
```

and put this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
    application.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
```

NSTimer will call your func in every callTime you want